# How can i play the video without streaming in IE8

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8, video-streaming, html5-video

If I play the video in IE8 using following codes, the video files storing in IE temporary folder. Is it possible to play video without storing the video files in temporary folder?

Even, Html5 video tag also storing video files in temporary folder.

Code 1:

```
<object width="100%" height="500px"
        type="video/x-ms-asf" url="testOne.mp4" data="testOne.mp4"
        classid="CLSID:6BF52A52-394A-11d3-B153-00C04F79FAA6">
        <param name="url" value="testOne.mp4">
        <param name="filename" value="testOne.mp4">                                     
        <embed type="application/x-mplayer2" src="testOne.mp4" width="100%" height="100%" autostart="true" showcontrols="true" pluginspage="http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/MediaPlayer/"></embed>
</object>
```

Code 2:

```
  <a  href="testOne.mp4"
             style="display:block;width:100%;height:460px" id="player"> </a>  
                
        <script>
            flowplayer("player", "flowplayer-3.2.17.swf");
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to "stream" the video live, instead of serving a static video file via flowplayer. You could upload the video file to a streaming server, and link the mms:// or rtsp:// link it generates to the player.

Streaming server is not freeware, but there are a few free places where you can upload your video and they provide the the streaming link for you.

Also, have a look at this. https://code.google.com/p/stream-m/